# JQuery and PHP - I cant show more than one submenu on my menu

Tags: php, jquery

I'm building a menu with submenus.

I'm using jQuery to show / hide submenus and I'm using PHP to receive the table values...

To put it in a nutshell, jQuery is there for visual effects, and php is used to show the right menu / submenu values from my database.

But I'm having some trouble here. When I click the menu link, only one submenu, the first one, shows,.

What can i do to show all the submenus?

I disabled jQuery many times, and it shows all the submenus when the jQuery script is disabled.

Menu View

```
<?php
    function menu($url,$name){
        echo "
            <ul>
            <li class='Item1'><a>$name</a></li>
            <ul class='submenu'>
        ";
    }
?>
<?php
    function submenu($suburl,$subname){
        echo "
            <li class='menuitem'><a>$subname</a></li>
            </ul>
            </ul>
        ";
    }
?>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> 



<style>
li{
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.menuitem{
    display:none;
}
</style> 

<script> 
jQuery(function () {
    $('.Item1 a').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().next().children('.menuitem').toggle();
    });
})
</script>
```

Menu Model

```
<?php
include(PATH_PUBLIC . '/admin/modules/menu/view/menu_view.php');
function menuModel()
{
    connect();
    $menu = ("SELECT * FROM menu");
    $val  = DB_array($menu, 'a+');
    $ii   = count($val);
    $ii   = $ii - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $ii; $i++) {
        $name = $val[$i]['friendlyname'];
        $url  = $val[$i]['url'];
        $id   = $val[$i]['menu_id'];
        menu($url, $name);

        $submenu = ("SELECT * FROM submenu WHERE menu_id=$id");
        $valor   = DB_array($submenu, 'a+');
        $qq      = count($valor);
        $qq      = $qq - 1;
        for ($q = 0; $q <= $qq; $q++) {
            $subname = $valor[$q]['name'];
            $suburl  = $valor[$q]['url'];
            submenu($suburl, $subname);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem relies in your submenu() function. Suppose that a menu item has 4 submenus. While in the first submenu, when submenu() is executed for the first time, you close both `<ul>` elements, which means that 2nd, 3rd and 4rth submenus are outside of the lists.

Change you submenu() function to

```
function submenu($suburl,$subname){

    echo "<li class='menuitem'><a>$subname</a></li>";
}
```

And close the `<ul>`s just after exiting the second `for`

```
 ......

   for ($q = 0; $q <= $qq; $q++) {
        $subname = $valor[$q]['name'];
        $suburl  = $valor[$q]['url'];
        submenu($suburl, $subname);
    }

    echo '</ul></ul>';
}
```